# Timezone in AggCat Service

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

For `postedDate`, `balanceDate`,..., the value is always a datetime with timezone. How does AggCat determine which timezone should be used? Does it depend on the certificate uploaded, or the location of the institution of the accounts or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The timezone is always in PST.